# xlrd to read Excel file and fetch values

Tags: xlrd

I am very new into Phython and I have to create a script. I want to read an Excel worksheet thorough Phython and output the cells value in my customized format.

My input Excel is :

```
B   Server1 NESLDS1 Local   T   Remote  F   Mltstdby    F   Group   60  Grpdef  60  Pad 
B   Server2 NESLDS2 Local   T   Remote  F   Mltstdby    F   Group   60  Grpdef  60  Pad
```

My question:

I am running one Phython code to get parameter's Value in each row, if it is string or integer, I want the value in quotes (`""`). Now if the value is Boolean i.e. `T` or `F` then I want the value without quotes.

My code :

```
import xlrd 
loc = ("C:\parameter.xlsx") 
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
for k in range(2,sheet.nrows):
 if sheet.cell_value(k,0)=="B":
  print ('\n')
  for i in range (2,14,2):
    print('"%s"' % sheet.cell_value(k,i),",",end='',sep='')
```

My current output is:

```
"NESLDS2","T","F","F","60","60",
"NESLDS2","T","F","F","60","60",
```

What I want :

I want `T` and `F` without quotes.

Comment: u can edit it too

Comment: can anybody please help me actually using the same loop I want string in double quote and for integer and Boolean I want value without quote.

Comment: When you say Phython, do you mean Python? I suggest you tag your question accordingly.